# Importing between two packages in python

Tags: python, package, importerror, python-import

I've got two packages in a project I'm working on (they're both in the project root): 
[image]

My `main.py` module in the `room` package needs to import a few modules from the `speechtotext` package. So I have imports in `main.py` that look like `from speechtotext.<modlue> import <something>`. I keep getting  an `ImportError` for these cross package imports.

How can I fix that import so it'll work properly?

Comment: Is `main.py` run as the main script perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters- Yes. It initializes some things and runs them.

Comment: You cannot run a script from inside a package. Move `main.py` *out* of `room` if you want both `room` and `speechtotext` to be packages.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Could I somehow make it so that the root directory is added to the `PYTHONPATH` without actually running `sys.path.insert`? 

For instance, I've got a `configuration.py` module in the root directory which many modules in other packages depend on. This will probably cause an `ImportError` as well.

Comment: If you have `main.py` located at the root, then that directory is automatically part of `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Either add `../speechtotext`'s path to the `PYTHONPATH` envar or just move speechtotext into the room folder. And don't forget to make an `__init__.py` file in speechtotext.